# Excel iferror for chart series or another workaround

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, offset

I have a very interesting issue. I'm trying to create a dynamic chart. This works well for the most part, however, when I change one of my parameters it makes the chart references invalid, which causes an incredibly annoying pop-up saying there are invalid references... I've tried to use an iferror([series formula],[generic formula]) but this is an invalid error.

So, I will accept one of two solutions... Either a way to use iferror() with my series, or a way to turn off the obnoxious pop-up message.

Some more pertinent information : 
I'm using dynamic named ranges
The dynamic ranges point to validation boxes (another thing I've considered is figuring out a way to auto-update the validation boxes since the issue is caused when validation box A is changed but B and C aren't changed yet.) The image attached will hopefully help explain....
[image]

Thank you for any assistance you can give!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the start date is later than the end date, right? Somewhere I usually use `MIN(StartDate,EndDate)` as my real start date and `MAX(StartDate,EndDate)` as my real end date.

Comment: The main problem is actually when I switch between fiscal types. So if I change from week to month, the month does not have the same values as the week does. So the named range is no longer a valid reference since it cannot find the start or end date. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, more complicated. I did a guest post on someone else's blog a long time ago that did something like this. Unfortunately that blog is now defunct, and I don't recall quite how I'd done it. I think I had used combo boxes and not DV for selecting the items, so the index of each combo was enough to look into a different column to get the appropriate item.

Comment: Hmm... Well if I ever figure it out I'll post it. In the meantime if you think of anything let me know!